GeoMesa/Accumulo custom iterator
Tech stack:
Accumulo 2.1.0
GeoMesa tools 4.0.1
Java custom client
Goal:
A custom iterator configured at scan time that would filter key/values based on certain constraints.
Object Usage:
DataStore from GeoTools API to retrieve key/values from the database.
Attempt:
I am trying to implement a custom iterator via Accumulo shell. I have created a prototype iterator in Java and put the jar into the pod. I also set the iterator to the table.
The iterator Java code has multiple slf4j logger log statements. The iterator extends Filter and implements OptionDescriber. Inside the accept() method, I have log.debug, log.info, log.error, and Stdn statements.
When I query the database, none of the statements show up in tserver logs or view logs. I can see logs in tservers (like GarabageCollector) but not from the iterator.
Also, in the accept method I am returning random true or false, but the results are still the same. I have setiter -scan to the table via Accumulo shell with priority set to 1.

What kind of filtering are you trying to do?  It may be possible with a CQL filter that the GeoTools API already supports.

@GeoJim I’m trying to add a custom filtering integrator for every key/val which requires a parameter be passed when querying.
